# Working with ehcache in offline enviroment without xsd

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, ehcache

I am using ehcache with spring. I want to deploy my application in an offline environment. I know I can download the xsd and give its location in xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation. Is it necessary to have an xsd?

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache does not require the XSD to be resolvable when starting, so no worry about that.

So you can have the XSD mentioned while developing to help with auto completion and still have no negative impact when your application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"

this location must be a absolute path

like this： ...Location="classpath:/yourPathInProject/ehcache.xml"

before this ,you need to download the ehcache.xml from http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd and put it in your project